# Not receiving push notifications until app is started manually

Tags: android, push-notification, appcelerator

Hope someone can help me with some tricky problem I have.

The point is that I have an appcelerator based app which incorporates push notifications service of Appcelerator Cloud Services. Everything goes fine when the user starts the app manually, even if it goes to background, it receives notifications.

However, if the phone is restarted, the notifications are no longer received.

I'm not sure if this is a manifest issue or what, so I will post it. If you need any other information, just request it!

Thank you very much,

Javier

---

### Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
<property name="acs-oauth-secret-production" type="string">XXXXX</property>
<property name="acs-oauth-key-production" type="string">XXXXX</property>
<property name="acs-api-key-production" type="string">XXXXX</property>
<property name="acs-oauth-secret-development" type="string">XXXXX</property>
<property name="acs-oauth-key-development" type="string">XXXXX</property>
<property name="acs-api-key-development" type="string">XXXXX</property>
<id>com.realzaragozasad.android</id>
<name>RealZaragoza</name>
<version>7</version>
<publisher>Real Zaragoza</publisher>
<url>http://www.realzaragoza.com</url>
<description>Aplicación móvil del Real Zaragoza para Android</description>
<copyright>2013 by Real Zaragoza</copyright>
<icon>appicon.png</icon>
<persistent-wifi>false</persistent-wifi>
<prerendered-icon>false</prerendered-icon>
<statusbar-style>default</statusbar-style>
<statusbar-hidden>false</statusbar-hidden>
<fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
<navbar-hidden>false</navbar-hidden>
<analytics>true</analytics>
<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">system</property>
<iphone>
    <orientations device="iphone">
        <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
    </orientations>
    <orientations device="ipad">
        <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
        <orientation>Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT</orientation>
        <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT</orientation>
        <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT</orientation>
    </orientations>
</iphone>
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <tool-api-level>8</tool-api-level>
    <manifest android:installLocation="preferExternal"
        android:versionCode="7" android:versionName="1.4">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    </manifest>
    <application>
        <service android:name="com.appcelerator.cloud.push.PushService"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.appcelerator.cloud.push.PushBroadcastReceiver" >
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="com.appcelerator.cloud.push.PushService.MSG_ARRIVAL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
          </intent-filter>
          <meta-data 
            android:name="com.appcelerator.cloud.push.BroadcastReceiver.ArrivalActivity"
            android:value="com.cocoafish.pushnotifications.ArrivalActivity" />
        </receiver>
    </application>
</android>
<mobileweb>
    <precache/>
    <splash>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <inline-css-images>true</inline-css-images>
    </splash>
    <theme>default</theme>
</mobileweb>
<modules>
    <module platform="commonjs">ti.cloud</module>
    <module platform="android">ti.cloudpush</module>
</modules>
<deployment-targets>
    <target device="blackberry">false</target>
    <target device="android">true</target>
    <target device="ipad">false</target>
    <target device="iphone">false</target>
    <target device="mobileweb">false</target>
    <target device="tizen">false</target>
</deployment-targets>
<sdk-version>3.1.0.GA</sdk-version>
</ti:app>
```

Comment: Please don't reveal your actual keys here for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question to share the knowledge to solve this, maybe is useful to someone else.

In my case, the problem was my app was installed in external storage (SD card) and this prevented the service which listened for notifications to run when the device rebooted.

Hope I helped someone!

Answer (score 0):

see if the app is push enabled in the application manager at the settings.

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer.